# span border-radius problem (in chrome) when I have a number at the first of its content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a span element that has a 16px border radius. When I add a number to the first of its content, its border-radius doesn't apply! I have this problem since I have upgraded chrome to the newest version.

```
<span>Hi</span> -> border-radius is 16px;

<span>4 Hi</span> -> border-radius should be 16px, but it's not! (when I inspect, it shows that 16 px is applied)
```

Comment: Your span tags are not closed. it should be `<span></span>`

Comment: Your code does not contain the css to produce the border radius. Also, can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Set `display:inline-block;` along with `border-radius`

Comment: Share code along with css for both cases

Comment: @Awais Great! would you please add this as an answer?

Comment: Good to hear that. Done adding as answer! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display:inline-block;` along with `border-radius`

Comment: For future do remember that `<span>` it self provides no visual change by itself and it didn't take any styles other then `color` and `background-color` until and unless its `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: You right. But the question is why it worked before updating chrome. And it works in Firefox without setting display to block or inline-block!

Comment: Browsers also update there structure and styles, they are adaptive to changes. I think may be they improve some CSS and Html styles in their latest release. May be that's what happened